# Android Application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and I want to create a condition in an if statement in my first activity, say Activity A that checks if that activity (e.g. Activity A) has been triggered by an intent from another Activity (say Activity B) and then do something. So if I was to trigger Activity A from say Activity C for example the if statement in Activity A wouldn't execute the code inside the if statement. I haven't written any code for it because I don't know how to approach it. I've written only pseudo code to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
class Activity A {

    if(Activity A was triggered by an intent from Activity B)
    {
        do something
    }

}
```

Help would be most appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) an answer if one of them helped.

Answer (score 3):

'putExtra()' in B and C and '.getExtras()' in A would be the easiest way. Have a look at steps 5 an 6 in

[The notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html)

(Plus you ought to check that the extras aren't null in Activity A to be on the safe side)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use startActivityForResult and then use onActivityResult to execute the code on return from whichever activity.